# Happy birthday Ramanujan!

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, graph-theory

On December 22 2019, Ramanujan would have been 132 years old. In his memory here are two puzzles around 132.

In the six vertices of each of these graphs place six positive integers that add up to 132, and such that two vertices are joined by an edge if, and only if, they have a common divisor greater than 1 (that is, they are not relatively prime).[image: puzzle]

Comment: Can we prove that the construction is impossible? specifically the left one?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Why not?

Comment: in fact both are impossible !??

Comment: must the integers be distinct?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton No

Comment: It's if and only if, so if two integers share a common divisor greater than 1, they should have an edge.

Comment: are the points of the outer triangle considered to be connected by an edge ?

Comment: Don't give up friends! Both puzzles have (unique) solutions as confirmed by Freddy Barrera, their creator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first one, With A starting from the top, B and C in the second.

> A = 9, B = 15, C = 21, D = 10, E = 70, F = 7

```
    A
  B   C
D   E   F
```

> [image: Spoiler Warning!]

For the second one with A, C, E in the top row

> A = 9, B = 21, C = 42, D = 35, E = 20, F = 5

```
A   C   E

 B   D   F
```

> [image]

dot files generated and verified with [this](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/32e61ae4add3c2ce68af14f7095377fd#file-92260-py) and the problem was solved manually based on choosing the factors that connected nodes will share.

Answer (score -1):

On  both figures, the numbers are shown on the vertices.

[image: triangles]

Comment: gcd(4,16)=4>1, but there's no edge.

Comment: @JMP. The question asked for a common factor greater than 1.

Comment: two vertices are joined by an edge **if, and only if**, they have a common divisor greater than 1